# Replace all numbers to "Zero" (0) JAVA

Tags: java

```
       String s1 = sc.next();
       String temp = "";
       s1 = s1 + " ";
       for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
         if (s1.charAt(i) >= '0' && s1.charAt(i) <= '9') {
   
           System.out.print('0');
   temp="";
         }else {
           temp = temp + s1.charAt(i);
         }
   
       }
     }
   }
```

I need to replace all numbers to zero in String. For example, Hell1234oo and the output Hell0000oo. The logic is almost right however i always get only 0000 without text. How can i fix it? Use only charAt

Comment: you are rewriting the whole temp string when a 0 occurs in `temp="";`

Comment: You might want to learn to step through your code with a debugger. That would reveal what's happening quite easily even if you can't see it directly in the code :) - And debugging is an essential skill for any developer.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with simple `replace by regexp` method of `String`:

```java
public static String maskNumbers(String str) {
    return str.replaceAll("\\d", "0");
}
```

And more native solution (but `replaceAll` does +/- the same):

```java
public static String maskNumbers(String str) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(str.length());

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);
        buf.append(Character.isDigit(ch) ? '0' : ch);
    }

    return buf.toString();
}
```

Comment: Note sure but there seems to be a constraint: "Use only charAt" :) - If that weren't there this would be my first though as well.

Comment: Probably the best but @Jens is the closest to a simple correction. I would create the `StringBuilder` with the original string and then mutate it though.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic isn't correct. You have to add the 0 to the temp not just print it to STDOUT:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s1 = "Hall123oo";
    String temp = "";
    s1 = s1 + " ";
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
        if (s1.charAt(i) >= '0' && s1.charAt(i) <= '9') {

            temp += "0";
        }else {
            temp += s1.charAt(i);
        }

    }
    System.out.print(temp);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Hall000oo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change every char to Integer object during the loop by the following code. If you don't get `NumberFormatException`, then change since this char is `Number`.

```
//  for loop start
    
String currentElement = "H";
Integer intValue = Integer.valueOf(currentElement);
// change the string char with '0'
    
// catch block
// do nothing
    
//for loop end
```

FULL CODE(without if blocks and different perspective):

```
    String s1 = "Hell1234oo";
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
        try {
            Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(s1.charAt(i)));
            result.append("0");
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            result.append(s1.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: I think the OP has the "is the char a digit" part already solved. The problem is in another part of the code - so your post doesn't really answer anything.

Comment: Working with exceptions here is very bad

Comment: Yes I know @Jens just I wanted to show you with another perspective. There are many way to detect the chars are Number or not. It was another approach. But it is not a large scale application then it can be useable.

Comment: @Thomas if you want full code, I edited.

Comment: In general exceptions should not be used for control flow, especially not in cases where a simple char range comparison is all that's needed.